# How can an administrator add a developer to an app

Tags: admin, facebook-page

I am an administrator for a page which was created for our company by a third party. Now, that third party is no longer with us and we are trying to add a developer account to the page. How can we achieve it?

Comment: How is this question about development?

Answer (score 28):

In your app settings at https://developers.facebook.com/apps

- Click 'edit settings'
- Click 'roles'
- Add the additional Administrators / Developers (by name if they're your friend on Facebook, by email address otherwise)

Your question isn't entirely clear, and it sounds like you could also be talking about a Page on Facebook.com - in that case

- Go to the Page
- Click 'Edit Page' in the top right
- Click 'Manage Admins' on the left
- Add the additional Administrators (by name if they're your friend on Facebook, by email address otherwise)